# python - Convert timezone and retrieve hour

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am looking to add three columns to my current dataframe (utc_date, apac_date, and hour).

I successfully obtain two of the three columns, however hour should be corresponding to apac_date (17) but it is returning the hour for utc_date (9).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the starting dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from tzlocal import get_localzone
from pytz import timezone
raw_data = {
        'id': ['123456'],
        'start_date': [pd.datetime(2017, 9, 21, 5, 30, 0)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id', 'start_date'])
df
```

Result:

```
id        start_date
123456    2017-09-21 05:30:00
```

Next, I convert the timezones for utc and apac based on the users current region.

```
local_tz = get_localzone()
df['utc_date'] = df['start_date'].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(local_tz).astimezone(timezone('utc')))
df['apac_date'] = df['utc_date'].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('utc').astimezone(timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')))
df
```

Result:

```
id        start_date            utc_date                    apac_date
123456    2017-09-21 05:30:00   2017-09-21 09:30:00+00:00   2017-09-21 17:30:00+08:00
```

Next, I retrieve the hour for the apac_date (it is giving me utc hour instead):

```
df['hour'] = df['apac_date'].apply(lambda x: int(x.strftime('%H')))
df
```

Result:

```
id       start_date            utc_date                    apac_date                   hour
123456   2017-09-21 05:30:00   2017-09-21 09:30:00+00:00   2017-09-21 17:30:00+08:00   9
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try using:

```
df['apac_date'] = df['utc_date'].apply(lambda x: x.tz_convert('Asia/Hong_Kong'))
```

I got errors with your above code with using `tz_localize()` on a timezone that has already been localized.